# Disable cowplot default for ggplots

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2, visualization, cowplot

The `ggplot2` add-on package, `cowplot`, has a nice function for plotting multiple plots called `plot_grid()`. Here's `plot_grid()` in action:

```
library(ggplot2); library(cowplot)

plot_a <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(mpg, wt)) + geom_point()
plot_b <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(mpg, disp)) + geom_point()

plot_grid(plot_a, plot_b, labels = c("A", "B"))
```

[image]

But note how loading `cowplot` changes the default style of plots. How can I load the `cowplot` package so that I can use the `plot_grid()` function but also disable the default plot styles that `cowplot` enforces?

Comment: could you not load `cowplot` and then just use `cowplot::plot_grid()`?

Comment: No -- as soon as you call `library(cowplot)`, ggplot's behavior changes.

Comment: As of version 1.0 cowplot no longer sets the default theme. https://wilkelab.org/cowplot/articles/introduction.html

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Just call `theme_set(theme_gray())` beforehand:

```
theme_set(theme_gray())
plot_grid(plot_a, plot_b, labels = c("A", "B"))
```

[image: Plot]

Then, if you want to go crazy with themes, you could install [`ggthemes`](https://github.com/jrnold/ggthemes) and simply replace `theme_gray()` with any theme you choose, or roll your own. Also see [this vignette](http://docs.ggplot2.org/dev/vignettes/themes.html) for styling individual elements.

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in the comments, once you've installed the `cowplot` package you can load the `plot_grid()` function with the `::` operator (see [What are the double colons (::) in R?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35240971/what-are-the-double-colons-in-r/35243471)) and cowplot won't change any `ggplot2` defaults.

```
> plot_a <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(mpg, wt)) + geom_point()
> plot_b <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(mpg, disp)) + geom_point()
> plot_grid(plot_a, plot_b, labels = c("A", "B"))
Error in plot_grid(plot_a, plot_b, labels = c("A", "B")) : 
  could not find function "plot_grid"

> cowplot::plot_grid(plot_a, plot_b, labels = c("A", "B"))
```

[image]

The issue comes when you load the entire `cowplot` package with `library()` or `require()`.

Comment: Nice , this just saved my bacon. This is a better answer than the accepted one, as it avoids the issue of overriding defaults entirely, rather than trying to override the override...